# Can I edit and sell Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL) licenced projects?

Tags: monetization, ms-pl

I downloaded a project that has Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL), can I edit the source code and sell it to customers?

Comment: Did you read the license?

Comment: @curiousdannii I wouldn't blame him, because the MsPL is so minimal that it's ambiguous. Selling is mentioned only in the context of patents, you aren't granted an explicit license to use the software, and it takes a little study to understand the scope of its copyleft,